# How to programatically set menu shortcut keys in .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

In my application, I have a "recent files" drop down menu. It will contain anywhere between 0 and 9 files to load. I want to set shortcut keys on these menu items such that Ctrl+1 loads the first file, Ctrl+2 loads the second, etc...

I understand that I need to set the `ShortcutKeys` property of the `ToolStripMenuItem` but I am looking for a way to do this inside of a loop. I have the files in an array that I read them from when initially building the menu.

I'd like to be able to do something like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
  files[i].ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control + Keys.D0 + i;
```

But addition of integer types to enum types is not allowed.

Is my best solution to create some function that encapsulates a switch statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
  if(i <= 12) files[i].ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control | (Keys)i+48;
```