# Populate ShortcutKeys in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-2.0

I have a [ToolStripMenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that serves as a drop down menu attached to the [MenuStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of my [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). The contents of this menu change depending on the status of the rest of the form and are populated in a loop.

The problem is that now I would like to add the functionality that the items in this menu have a keyboard shortcut based on their position in the list. The first item in the list should be Ctrl+1, the second Ctrl+2, etc.

Since [ShortcutKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.shortcutkeys%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is set using the [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) enum I do not know how I could map an incrementing value to the proper values in the enum. I had hoped something like this would work, but it did not:

```
newToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control | (Keys.D0 + menuItemNumber++);
```

**Edit**

There may be something else going on. According to [this asker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3096757/1111886) my initial solution should have worked, and the solution proposed by [Migol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70918/migol) produces the same result. The value in ShortcutKeys is shown to be some odd combination of characters with no apparent pattern.

Comment: You are just getting confused by what the debugger displays.  Which gets confused because the Keys enum has the [Flags] attribute, that is only partially correct.  Move on, you don't have a real problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [About override ProcessCMDKey in c# winform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561986/about-override-processcmdkey-in-c-sharp-winform)

Comment: @HansPassant Ah yes that makes sense, but if both solutions are displaying the same thing I'm likely setting it correctly and there is some other reason why it is not working. Oh and to your second comment my problem is not with me checking the value. I don't care what it looks like to me from the code but it sill needs to fire the event when the keys are pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing, but the problem completely unrelated to anything mentioned in this post. It was a stupid mistake made by my own bad programming habits in combination with a typo.

In my original ask I changed the name of my local variable from `processorToolStripMenuItem` to `newToolStripMenuItem` since this made more sense out of the context of the application. The item I was adding it to was a field named `procesorToolStripMenuItem` which as you can see is missing an 's'.

For the line of code setting the keyboard shortcut I made the same typo and was thus setting the keyboard shortcut of the wrong thing. They should never have been named something so similar to one another in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enum.Parse` method like this:

```
string enumName = "D" + menuItemNumber++;
newToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control | (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), enumName);
```

[Enum.Parse documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Well my string would be "D" + menuItemNumber++ in this case, but I'm beginning to suspect there is more going on than meets the eye given this gives the same result as my idea which apparently worked for [this asker](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3096757/1111886).

Comment: @Fr33dan your solution has one major setback - it contains magic number and it's harder to understand.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by magic number, but I suppose it is a little trickier to understand. Either way since they produce the same results my problem must not be in setting the value but rather something else. I'm thinking it may be related to setting the keyboard shortcut after the form is opened but I'm still investigating.

Comment: @Fr33dan Magic number is any constant that is not clear to the reader what it means. In your case it's `47`.

Comment: Oh I (unlike the solution linked) cast Keys.D0 to and int instead of hard coding its int value specifically to avoid it coming out of nowhere. It would be terribly confusing on its own.

Comment: @Fr33dan yes, this would be a very acceptable solution